# how to change value of type in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the following dictionary: `d = {s: {0:{'n','s'}, 1:{'s'} }}`

How can I change the value of `{'n','s'}(set)` to `['n','s']` as short as possible.

Because I have to print it's value in the form `0:['n','s'], 1:['s']`

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
 for key, value in d['s'].iteritems(): 
     d['s'][key] = list(d['s'][key])
 print d
```

Input:

```
d = {s: {0:{'n','s'}, 1:{'s'} }}
```

Output:

```
{'s': {0: ['s', 'n'], 1: ['s']}}
```